ubuntu cloud backup?
I want to back up a machine that sits in the HETZNER cloud
Once manually to have in case of disaster.
My website has 3 websites that are published in the world using WORDPRESS
Apparently I also need to back up the DATE BASE.
The machine in my cloud is:
Linux 5.15.0-101-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 5 20:16:58 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
My question is how do I make one manual backup that includes the system that includes everything - both at the host level and in converting the files in one file in case the server is completely deleted

This is not related to the OS you work with: check the  HETZNER portal. You do not make system backups from inside a cloud. You do that from the console of that cloud. Same goes for your personal files: you should have 2 "disks": one system, one private. From the console you back them up by creating a copy of your disks.

Rarely is it worthwhile to backup an entire server unless you need to keep a static version of an OS with its associated software running in an air-gapped situation. That said, you can easily have the MySQL database exported, the Apache configuration file saved, and the contents of the www directory compressed and stored in a single file. This can be done with a batch job nightly with the file being sent via SSH (or another method) to another system for safe-keeping.

Through the cloud console, you can only charge for a fee
I want to create a backup file of the server - mainly for websites and download from the server itself and save the backup locally
